# Play framework. receive "A JPA error occurred"

Tags: playframework

I am new to play framework. tried to follow the tutorial http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/guide2

when i added the following user class (as instructed in tutorial)

```
package models;

import java.util.*;
import javax.persistence.*;

import play.db.jpa.*;

@Entity
public class User extends Model {

    public String email;
    public String password;
    public String fullname;
    public boolean isAdmin;

    public User(String email, String password, String fullname) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.fullname = fullname;
    }

}
```

I receive the following error:

> A JPA error occurred (Cannot start a JPA manager without a properly configured database): No datasource configured

what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might need to configure the database in the application.conf.  As you are running the tutorial, using the H2 in-memory database is sufficient.  To do that, just uncomment the following line in the application.conf:

```
db=mem
```

To read more about the application.conf configuration parameters, go [here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/configuration).

Comment: you are correct. i wonder why they did not point this out in the tutorial ? thanks.

Comment: It looks to be mentioned on the first page of the tutorial: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/guide1